# Which Messaging Protocol to use?

Tags: websocket, chat, messaging, mqtt

I am going to integrate chat module in my application. It's a mobile application having front end in swift and backend in spring boot. So my chat module will have functionalities :)

```
1) There will be a one to one chat,not a group chat
2) i have to send push notification to user when user goes offline or app closed
3) i have to show online users list on user's dashboard
4) i have to store messages in database
5) User can send images,videos in chat
```

I know these functionalities are common in all modern mobile applications.

I am very new to messaging protocols,please suggest me a best protocol as well suited to my requirements.

Any advice will be helpful,Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the [The Message Session Relay Protocol (MSRP)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4975)

You can find a comparison [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_instant_messaging_protocols).